# How to activate nVidia cards programmatically on new MacBookPros for CUDA programming?

Tags: c, macos, cuda, gpu

The new MacBookPros come with two graphic adapters, the Intel HD Graphics, and the NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M. OS X switches back and forth between them, depending on the workload, detection of an external monitor, or activation of Rosetta.

I want to get my feet wet with CUDA programming, and unfortunately the CUDA SDK doesn't seem to take care of this back-and-forth switching. When Intel is active, no CUDA device gets detected, and when the NVidia card is active, it gets detected. So my current work-around is to use the little tool gfxCardStatus (http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus/) to force the card on or off, just as I need it, but that's not satisfactory.

Does anybody here know what the Apple-blessed, Apple-recommended way is to (1) detect the presence of a CUDA card, (2) to activate this card when present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, supposedly MacOsX should switch back and forth when needed, and apparently it doesn't consider CUDA.

In Snow Leopard Apple introduced OpenCL, which is supposed to be used to program the GPU by any application, this is probably Apple's recommended way of achieving that, instead of CUDA.

Comment: Good point. My reasoning was: CUDA has been available on Linux, OS X, Win32 for a long time, so it's really cross-platform, but OpenCL looked to me like an Apple attempt of a lock-in.

Comment: There are implementations of OpenCL from nvidia and AMD and it is not controlled by Apple so i doubt you would be locked in by going the opencl way.

Comment: Any idea about performance? If I know what I'm doing (i.e. which hardware is used, number of cores, registers, size of memory etc.), will I be able to get the same performance out of OpenCL as I would get out of CUDA?

Answer (score 1):

I am testing CUDA and OpenCL on the NVidia-Platform. All my application (i have to write it with cuda and opencl framework) achieve the same performance (measured in MFlops).
BUT: if you use local memory optimization for NVidia, than there is some problems to run this application with ATI-GPU. So this is not really cross platform:(

Comment: I never really bought into that ATI-nVidia compatibility. When we optimize for a certain hardware we always optimize against some other hardware. I was more concerned that going through OpenCL would not be as efficient as using CUDA directly. If I understood you correctly, this is not the case, and I can safely dump the CUDA documentation and start reading OpenCL docs...